# Python Tkinter IntVar with Checkbutton not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating Tkinter checkbuttons from a list of text. I want to set checkbutton enabled by default in some cases. I assign a variable and store the variable in a list to be used later to check the state of checkbutton.

However! The variable doesn't seem to be assigned to the checkbutton at all..! I don't know where is the problem.

This is the gui list:
(item, text, state)

```
[('checkbox', 'Option 1', 1), ('checkbox', 'Option 2', 0), ('checkbox', 'Option 3', 1)]
```

And: `var = ['' for i in range (len(gui))]`

This is the code:

```
for i in range(len(gui)):
    if (gui[i][0] == 'checkbox'):
        var[i] = tk.IntVar(value=int(gui[i][2])
        created_gui[i] = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=gui[i][1], variable=var[i], command=stateChanged) 
        created_gui[i].pack(anchor = "w")
```

[image: GUI is created like this]

I want to set the checkbutton enabled by default in case `gui[i][2] == 1` but it doesn't want to work!

Full Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

def stateChanged():
    pass

my_filetypes = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt')]
filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Please select a file:", filetypes=my_filetypes)
file = open(filePath, 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
gui = []

for line in lines:
    firstChar = line[0]
    text = line.strip()

    if (firstChar == '/'):
        if (text[-4:].lower() == 'true'):
            default = 1
            text = text[1:-4]
        
        elif (text[-5:].lower() == 'false'):
            default = 0
            text = text[1:-5]
        gui.append(('checkbox', text, default)) #Add checkbox to GUI
   
intVars = []
checkBtns = []
window = tk.Tk()

for i in gui:
    intVars.append(tk.IntVar(value=i[2]))
    created_gui = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=i[1], variable=intVars[-1], command=stateChanged) 
    created_gui.pack(anchor = "w")
    checkBtns.append(created_gui)

window.mainloop()
```

[image: Full Code Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `len()` and `range()` to loop through the list instead use `in`.
To append to a list use `.append`

sample code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def stateChanged():
    pass

window = tk.Tk()
gui = [('checkbox', 'Option 1', 1), ('checkbox', 'Option 2', 0), ('checkbox', 'Option 3', 1)]


intVars = []
checkBtns = []

for i in gui:

    intVars.append(tk.IntVar(master=window, value=i[2]))
    created_gui = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=i[1], variable=intVars[-1], command=stateChanged) 
    created_gui.pack(anchor = "w")
    checkBtns.append(created_gui)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help, but all checkbuttons are still unchecked (false). I added a print statement to give me intVars[-1].get() for each button and this is what I received: https://i.imgur.com/GJhVJUV.png [As you can see in GUI, all checkbuttons still unchecked!] Thanks for your time.

Comment: @MahmoudEmbaby can you add your complete code. If it is too lengthy then provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am very thankful to both of you, TheLizzard and JacksonPro. You are the best people! The problem was the missing (master=window) in IntVar() After adding it, it worked very well! Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @TheLizzard Keep in mind, to not edit the users code without their permission.

Comment: @CoolCloud Sorry. I thought that the changes were minor (just tried to improve readability and make the code more stable). I didn't even know that OP had more than 1 `Tk()` objects.

Comment: @JacksonPro You might want to add `master=window` to the `IntVar()` because that was was part of the solution to OP's problem.

Comment: @TheLizzard I have no problem if ppl edit my code as long as they don't do it with bad intention. Also, I can't find two instances of  `Tk()` in OP's code.

Comment: @JacksonPro I think that when OP was creating a small example to post here they might have removed the second case of `Tk()`.

Comment: Neither do I mind people editing my answer(with good intention) but some people actually do mind and makes big fuss out of it. Learned it the hard way ;) @TheLizzard So its always best to just comment the changes or ask for permission to edit.

Comment: @CoolCloud ok I will do that in the future